# Generate one declaration file for TypeScript library

Tags: typescript, declaration, tsc

I developed a library, which also contains TypeScript files, in Visual Studio 2013. The files are compiling correctly to JS files (AMD).

What I want is to create a single declaration file for this lib, but this does not work:

```
tsc --declaration --module AMD --out out.d.ts [files.ts]
```

Can someone please lead me to the right path?

TypeScript 0.9.1.1 is used.

Comment: Check https://api-extractor.com/.

Answer (score 5):

Its because you are providing `.d.ts` to out which will overwrite the declaration file with js contents.
Also, you need to remove `module amd` because that works on per file basis (not --out friendly, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1)

So, try:

```
tsc [files.ts] --declaration --out out.js
```

which will generate `out.d.ts`

Comment: Changed to "tsc --declaration --module AMD --out out.js [files.ts]", which now generates js and d.ts files, BUT seperatly for each source file.

Comment: Now I get: 'error TS5037: Cannot compile external modules unless the "--module" flag is provided.'

Comment: If your library is designed to use AMD you cannot have it merged to a single js (for which you will use r.js) or single .d.ts (for which there isnt any alternative solution) using tsc

Comment: `out` is renamed to `outFile` and Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside `--outFile`. (2018)

Answer (score 1):

You could always do it after the fact with command line calls.  In Visual Studio, use the following as a post-build event command line call:

```
del $(OutDir)combined.d.ts
type $(OutDir)*.d.ts > $(OutDir)combined.d.ts
```

It might need to be `$(ProjectDir)Some\Other\Path\*.d.ts`, etc.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/42x5kfw4.aspx) for more

Comment: this will not work, since local imports will not be resolved (ie: `import { plugin1 } from './lib';`)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Andy W's answer you will want to remove the reference path lines. Use FIND to do this.

```
del "$(ProjectDir)bin\combined.d.ts"
type "$(ProjectDir)*.d.ts" "$(ProjectDir)subFolder1\*.d.ts" "$(ProjectDir)subFolder2\*.d.ts" | FIND /V /I "/// <reference path="  > "$(ProjectDir)bin\combined.d.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Generate one declaration file for Typescript lib.

You don't need to do that (or at least you haven't provided a use case for it).

Your output folder e.g. `/module/bar` should look like:

- `index.js` < generated `.js` for `/module/bar.ts`
- `index.d.ts` < generated `.d.ts` for `/module/bar.ts`

And when users require `/module/bar` *runtime* resolves to `.js` and TypeScript type system resolves to `.d.ts` automatically.

## Examples

- Vast number of TypeScript npm modules out there. Here is [one of mine](https://github.com/typestyle/typestyle).
- [NodeJS quickstart covers creating npm modules](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html)

Comment: I've upvoted b/c I liked that library of yours so much as an example, however, a use case could be a library that is bundled into one file prior to packaging, so having all types in a single file could be useful in this case. I'm not sure at all if this is the same as what the OP had in mind originally, just saying.